# HTTPS enablement for WCF service hosted as windows service

Tags: wcf

We have a WCF service hosted as windows service. Now we are trying to enable https for the URL exposed by this service. We are getting an error as follows "Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]." Below is my config:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ApplicationName" value="WCFService"/>
    <add key="MassiveServiceURL" value="http://ausuwcdmcctrl01.aus.amer.dell.com:9000/MassiveService/" />
    <add key="StartODMService" value="true"/>
    <add key="MassivePackageDescription" value="AFP Sync"/>
    <add key="MassiveCustomerGroup" value="BTOA"/>
    <add key="MassivePriority" value="HIGH"/>
    <add key="MassiveAccount" value="americas\ServiceMassiveTest"/>
    <add key="AFPWcfServiceURL" value="https://kuliwafpweb01.kul.apac.dell.com:8900/AfpWcfService/"/>

    <add key="MassiveWebServiceBinding" value="BasicHttpBinding_IMassiveService"/>
    <add key="ArchiveGAFPFolder" value="GAFP"/>
  </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AFPDBConnString" connectionString="Data Source=PENDWCDDB01.pen.apac.dell.com;Initial Catalog=AFPSIT;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="GlobalAfp4Log" connectionString="data source=PENDWCDDB01.pen.apac.dell.com;initial catalog=AFPSITLOG;integrated security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="AgileDBConnString" connectionString="6923977bd9a34ce291c775ca531efe7f64c2cf1422100eb1408676deb90a878c9de0fe037305b00724e522e7387851f197446de48beb12ec6848189ce7f28ee8b4648559d951b888e7f0a4fe4595b47462bb0d420cf1e893f18b6b5e4e14c35c75d8f09481f6761d648ce08d8b1fd51ba7c749bb8e5d4a4dd4cde96841e94f3a3c735fe2a641ce655b875c1fb1d1043f3d848ffe197cd73ab6b4e268ce9df815f395d1f2cadef247698d770c20102aeb" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="AFPWcfServiceLibrary.AfpWcfService" behaviorConfiguration="AFPWCFService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://kuliwafpweb01.kul.apac.dell.com:8900/AfpWcfService/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="AFPWcfServiceLibrary.IAfpWcfService" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IGAFPPartsInformationService" />
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="AFPWcfServiceLibrary.IGAFPPartsInformationService" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IGAFPPartsInformationService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>

      <service name="AFPWcfServiceLibrary.OdmWcfService" behaviorConfiguration="AFPWCFService" >
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="AFPWcfServiceLibrary.IOdmWcfService" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://kuliwafpweb01.kul.apac.dell.com:8900/OdmWcfService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AFPWCFService">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="65536000" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="400" maxConcurrentInstances="400" maxConcurrentSessions="100"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>




    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAfpWcfService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
         openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00"
               allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
               maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text"
               textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IGAFPPartsInformationService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00"
                      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text"
                      textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMassiveService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
            openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="6553600" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="1638400"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="1638400" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="">
              <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
            </transport>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>

        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IArchiveService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="6553600" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="1638400"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="1638400" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
            openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="52428800" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
            allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="320000" maxStringContentLength="8192000" maxArrayLength="50384000"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096000" maxNameTableCharCount="1638400" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="true" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://ausuwcdmcctrl01.aus.amer.dell.com:9000/MassiveService/"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMassiveService"
              contract="IMassiveService"
              name="BasicHttpBinding_IMassiveService" />

      <endpoint address="http://kuliwafparc01.kul.apac.dell.com:8732/AFPArchiveServiceLibrary/ArchiveService/"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IArchiveService"
          contract="Dell.AFP.Common.ServiceClient.ArchiveService.IArchiveService"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IArchiveService" />
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Try to add `<add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" />`  to the <protocolMapping>. Default sscheme for wsHttpBinding is http.

Comment: Added as suggested but still the same error